# Test set, and assessment of algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, classification, optimization, dataset

I have a very basic machine learning question (or maybe not so basic).

Suppose we have a training set, and a test set (im leaving out validation set here). We have some parameter vector that we found from the training set - say $\mathbf{w}$. We can assess the accuracy (or misclassification rate) of this parameter vector on the test set.

Is it different if we assess the COST FUNCTION on the TEST set (using parameter vector that we estimated from the training set)? How will it reflect the quality of the classifier (in comparison to accuracy, for example)?

Answer (score 1):

The cost function is something that is used for training. You calculate it so you can minimize it and get you parameter vector $w$.

It is not very useful to calculate its value for the test set. That being said, if for some reason you wanted to calculate the loss function for the test set, you would use the parameters $w$ calculated using the training set.

If you calculated a new set of parameters $w$ for your test set, you would just have turned your test set into another training set.

Comment: Yes, of course $\mathbf{w}$ is not adjusted using test set - only training set is used for training. But after training, $\mathbf{w}$ is used to compute, for example, hinge loss for SVM on test set. I cannot see how this estimation of classifier is worse than accuracy for example.

Comment: I am just having trouble understanding why you would need the loss of the test set? Are trying to use it as a performance metric?

Comment: Yes. And I'd like to know if there is some fundamental reason why not to, and how it compares to, say, accuracy. As for loss functions - it could be hinge loss in my particular case

Comment: The main one I can think of is that since different classifiers have different loss functions you will not be able to compare them directly. Also depending on how your loss function is implemented, if it is not scaled with the number of examples you can not even compare them for the same classifier. I really advise you use the usual accuracy,  AUC, precision recall. These do not have any of the problems mentioned.